# Why use XAML in visual studio express for windows 8?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

i'm trying to do an application for Windows 8 and i'm following a guide on channel9.msdn
I cant understand why they use XAML to create textbox, label or other controls.
There's a reason ? There's a form which is much faster: simply drag & drop controls into the UI.
So why use XAML ?
Thanks all and sorry for my english :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAML supports laying out the form so that if you resize the window, the controls contained in the window are always consistently positioned according to the layout.
If you just drag and drop, you will see that the designers uses margins to position the controls. When you resize the window, they kind of keep the same position and are not going to be well positioned anymore.
This layouting is the essence of WPF. Just read a tutorial about layouting in WPF.

Comment: see an example here : http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2011/08/02/understanding-xaml.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop creation of UIs when using XAML creates very poorly formatted XAML and since there are a significant number of things which are most easily done in XAML (data templates for instance), it's easier to simply construct your UI in XAML from the start.